# Base64 en python3

Tags: python-3.x

He visto programas que para ya sea subir archivos de forma remota o para recibirlos de forma remota, usan base64.

Lo mas raro es que copie el código y lo modifique, quitandole así lo de base64, y para mi asombro este siguió funcionando con total normalidad.

Es ahí mi duda, cual es la implementacion de este modulo llamado base64, según vi en la documentación lo que hacia este modulo era codear bytes para pasarlos a texto plano, y esto lo recomendaban hacer en medios donde todo era texto plano, como la web en general o correos electrónicos.
(Así lo entendí yo).

Espero me puedan ayudar (teoría y practica) para hacer uso de el en mis proyectos de ser necesario y útil.

El código del cual hablaba es el siguiente:

```
elif answer[:8] == "download":
                with open(answer[9:],mode = "rb") as file_download:
                    self.cliente.send(base64.b64encode(file_download.read()))



elif answer[:6] == "upload":
        with open(answer[7:],mode = "wb") as file_upload:
            datos = self.cliente.recv(1000000)
                datos = datos.decode("utf-8")
                    file_upload.write(base64.b64decode(datos))

elif answer == "screenshot":
        try:
            self.screenshot()
            with open("monitor-1.png",mode = "rb") as screen:
                self.cliente.send(base64.b64encode(screen.read()))
                #self.cliente.send(screen.read())
            os.remove("monitor-1.png")
```

Lo que hice fue quitar el base64 que hay dentro de cada write, y este siguió funcionando con normalidad. Se podían enviar y recibir datos (documentos de word,EXE'S,etc), ademas de esto cuando tomaba una captura remota, cuando la abría para ver como había quedado, esta se veía bien, completa y sin ningún tipo de error en la imagen.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu comprensión de la utilidad de base64 es correcta. Me extiendo un poco más.

## Bytes, ASCII y restricciones

Como bien sabemos la información se almacena y transmite en bytes. Un byte es un grupo de 8 bits y por tanto admite 2<sup>8</sup> diferentes valores, que son 256.

Debido a la existencia del estándar ASCII, varios de esos 256 valores pueden interpretarse como un carácter imprimible (por ejemplo, el código binario `01000001`, que en base 10 sería el valor 65, representa a la letra `'A'`). Sin embargo, ya que ASCII usa sólo 7 bits, la mitad de los posibles valores de un byte no serían códigos ASCII válidos, y de la mitad que sí lo son, no todos son caracteres imprimibles (los 32 primeros códigos, desde `00000000` hasta `00011111`, son caracteres de control, que no representan ningún símbolo escrito).

Muchos protocolos de internet están basados en texto (ej: HTTP, SMTP) por lo que esperan que los contenidos a transmitir sean ASCII. En muchos casos además limitan a sólo ASCII imprimible, e incluso dentro de los imprimibles se puede restringir aún más qué carácteres se permiten, eliminando muchos signos de puntuación que puedan tener significado especial dentro del protocolo.

Para poder transmitir contenidos arbitrarios binarios, es necesario recodificarlos a otro formato que asegure que cada byte transmitido sólo puede tomar ciertos valores permitidos, y decodificarlo otra vez cuando se reciba. Base64 es una posible forma de hacerlo (no la única).

## Cómo funciona Base64

Como su nombre indica, Base64 restringe los posibles caracteres a transmitir a un subconjunto de ASCII compuesto por sólo 64 caracteres. En concreto serían todas las letras mayúsculas del inglés (26 caracteres), las minúsculas (otros 26), los dígitos de 0 a 9 (10 más y ya van 62), y los signos `/` y `+`. Además también utiliza el signo `=` opcionalmente como relleno al final de la secuencia.

Ya que 64 es 2<sup>6</sup> resulta que el "alfabeto" usado por base64 se puede codificar con 6 bits. Por tanto el algoritmo usado es:

- Se agrupan los bytes del mensaje a transmitir de 3 en 3.
- Cada grupo está formado por tanto por 24 (8*3) bits
- Se dividen esos 24 bits en grupos de 6 bits, salen 4 grupos (6*4=24)
- Cada grupo de 6 bits es un número entre 0 y 63
- Se convierte cada uno de esos números a una letra mayúscula, o minúscula, o un dígito, o uno de los símbolos `/` o `+`. Por ejemplo, si el número es 0, el caracter será `A`, etc. Hay una tabla de equivalencias.
- El caracter resultante se codifica como ASCII

Así pues, cada grupo de 3 bytes en el original da lugar a 4 caracteres ASCII en la codificación. Pero estos caracteres serán imprimibles, elegidos del subconjunto de 64 antes mencionado.

Observarás que base64 resuelve un problema (permite enviar bytes arbitrarios de forma compatible con protocolos de texto), pero introduce otro: el tamaño de la información a enviar ha crecido. Si originalmente eran 600 bytes, tras pasarlos a base64 serán 800. Cada grupo de 3 se convierte en 4.

Ejemplo:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(b"Hola que tal")
b'SG9sYSBxdWUgdGFs'
>>> base64.b64encode(bytearray([1, 2, 0, 240, 232, 17, 8]))
b'AQIA8OgRCA=='
```

Fíjate que en el primer ejemplo sería bastante absurdo usar base64, pues la información (el mensaje "Hola que tal") ya está compuesto por ASCII puro. No obstante puede hacerse con objeto de "ofuscar" ligeramente el mensaje (no da ninguna seguridad criptográfica, pues la decodificación es trivial, pero evita que "sin querer" alguien vea el mensaje).

El segundo caso muestra una utilidad más real, ya que en este caso la secuencia de bytes contiene valores no imprimibles (1, 2, 0, 17, 8) y algunos no ascii (240, 232), pero como ves la codificación resultante está compuesta exclusivamente por códigos alfanuméricos (el `==` del final en este caso es porque a la secuencia de bytes original le faltarían 2 bytes más para ser múltiplo de 3).

En resumen, Base64 debe usarse en contextos en los que el protocolo te obligue a transmitir los datos en ascii imprimible (como el cuerpo de un email, o parte de una URL, una cabecera HTTP como por ejemplo las *cookies*, o las imágenes codificadas en un campo `data` del tag `<img>` en HTML). Si el protocolo en cambio te admite datos binarios (como el cuerpo de una respuesta GET, o de una petición POST), no necesitas usar base64 en ese caso.

## Tu duda

Planteas una curiosa cuestión:

> Lo mas raro es que copie el codigo y lo modifique, quitandole asi lo de base64, y para mi asombro este siguio funcionando con total normalidad.

Esto es bastante raro. Sin saber qué estabas haciendo, con qué librería y para qué protocolo, resulta difícil explicarlo. Si el destino estaba esperando algo codificado en base64 y lo enviaste sin codificar, cuando el destino intente decodificarlo lo más probable será que encuentre errores, y si no (porque casualmente tu mensaje tenía sólo letras y numeros), la decodificación daría otro mensaje.

La única explicación que se me ocurre es que estés usando una biblioteca para hacer la transmisión y que esta biblioteca admite como parámetro tanto una cadena `str` como una secuencia de `byte`s, y que la propia biblioteca se ocupe de codificarlos en base64 si no se lo das ya codificado. De todas formas, si muestras exactamente el código en cuestión, podremos intentar resolver el enigma.

Comment: He ampliado la pregunta (agregue el código), para ver si se puede hallar el ¿por que? de este suceso.

Comment: @retr0 Ok, ese código entiendo que es la parte del servidor ¿y la del cliente? Porque si quitaste los base64 también en el cliente, es lógico que funcione. En ese caso los datos se están transmitiendo directamente en binario. Ya que no parece que estés usando un protocolo como HTTP, sino uno propio que opera directamente a nivel de socket, y en el que escribes tanto el cliente como el servidor, puedes elegir si transmitir en base64 o en bytes directamente. Lo segundo sería más eficiente (menos consumo de red).

Comment: Dale todo ha quedado muy claro. Oye de casualidad sabes uno como hace para saber cuanto buffer implementar para recibir algo?. Es decir el buffer es lo que va dentro de recv(), en imágenes he visto que se usa 1000000, en texto amplio se usa 2048, y en texto corto 1024. Como se yo cuanto usar respecto a x dato?

Comment: No sabes. De hecho, aunque pongas 100000 nada te asegura que `recv()` no reciba mucho menos, por problemas de red, y más tarde llegue el resto (pero necesitarías otro `recv()`, quizás muchos). Nunca sabes si lo que has recibido con un `recv()` es el fichero completo o falta más que vendrá luego. Por eso son necesarios protocolos que especifiquen, antes de enviar el fichero, cuántos bytes lo componen. Así sabrás qué poner en el `recv()` y también si te ha llegado todo o no.